# Gradle The task name ':subproject:build' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]

Tags: gradle

```
The task name ':subproject-workflow:build' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |].
```

I am upgrading from Gradle 4 to 6.

How can I replace this statement in which I call the subproject tasks from the parent folder?

Full code in the parent is

```
task build {
    task(":subproject1:build").dependsOn(task(":subproject2:build"))
}
```